# How to set digital clock font Android

Tags: android

I am designing an app with digital clock. I have designed that except the font part. I want to show the clock font in "digital clock font"(like in digital watches) instead of normal font. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's probably simplest to prepare ten images for the digits and switch which ones are visible to animate your clock.

Comment: Thanks Jim. But is not that cause performance kind of issue like screen blinking etc., (as I need to show seconds in the clock..)?